# Make "[feedback site]" a proper link in digest emails

Tags: bug, markdown, hyperlinks, email

The [feedback site](https://meta.stackexchange.com) link is Stack Exchange digest emails is rendered incorrectly. I expected a proper link, as above, and got markdown:

`Questions? Comments? Let us know on our [feedback site](https://meta.stackexchange.com).`

[image: feedback site]